# Error in TensorFlow building tensorflow::EagerContext' has no member named 'GetContextId'

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel, odroid

I'm Trying to install TensorFlow (c++ lib) by source compiling on `ODROID XU4` but get error while `eager` become build.
Error is:

```
ERROR: /home/odroid/buildFile/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/BUILD:148:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager:remote_tensor_handle_data' failed (Exit 1)
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/remote_tensor_handle_data.cc: In function 'void tensorflow::{anonymous}::DestoryRemoteTensorHandle(tensorflow::EagerContext*, tensorflow::eager::EagerClient*, tensorflow::uint64, tensorflow::uint64, int)':
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/remote_tensor_handle_data.cc:30:12: error: 'class tensorflow::EagerContext' has no member named 'GetContextId'; did you mean 'NewContextId'?
   if (ctx->GetContextId() != context_id) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
            NewContextId
Target //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so failed to build
```

How I can fix it?
OR Is Impossible for me to disable building this module in bazel command?
tnx.

Comment: Is `bazel` the preferred/recommended environment for building tensorflow? If not, switch to building with the documented tool. Get it to work THEN try using other tools. ELSE did you try changing references of `GetContextID` to `NewContextId`? You should always include what you have tried to resolve the problem inside your question above (when you first post the message).

Comment: Hi @shellter. Yes I Done it and ```Bazel``` is prefered & recommended by TensorFlow Team.